# Modify included YAML file

Tags: yaml, pyyaml

I have 2 yaml files.

Let's call the first login.yaml:

```
id: 1
login:
    user: name
    pass: secret
```

I am including this file in another yaml file called config.yaml. Now I want to add a new key (which I will call example) to the dictionary after I have included it in config.yml which would look like that:

```
login_info:
    !include login.yaml
    example: random
```

Obviously this is not working. In fact, each line is working separately but it is when the last 2 lines are combined that things go wrong.

It should be noted that YAML format is handled with pyyaml which makes including possible.

Comment: This looks very similar to https://github.com/tanbro/pyyaml-include/issues/7#issuecomment-917827409, in this case `example` cannot be added as the third key of `login_info` because the first two keys `id` and `login` are part of a separately parsed object. I guess it would work if you use an extra level `credentials: !include login.yaml` for example.

Answer (score 1):

PyYAML supports the [merge key](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html):

```yaml
login_info:
    <<: !include login.yaml
    example: random
```

However merge key processing happens before calling custom constructors (which I assume is how you implement `!include`) so you would need to process `!include` earlier in the pipeline, e.g. by extending the parser or the composer. This is doable but not trivial.

Another possibility would be to implement `!include` like the merge key:

```yaml
login_info:
    !include : login.yaml
    example: random
```

That's an empty key with the tag `!include`. I am not entirely sure whether this can be implemented via custom constructors since you'd need to be able to access the parent mapping in the constructor of `!include`.

A variant that is certainly implementable via custom constructors is this:

```yaml
login_info: !include
  path: login.yaml
  extend:
    example: random
```